# Boggle dice set letter distribution algorithm

Tags: probability-distributions, recreational-mathematics, dice

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Boggle letter probability](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/42405/boggle-letter-probability)

What algorithm have the creators of the word game [Boggle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boggle) used to come up with these dice sets?

```
New Version | Old Version
AAEEGN      | AACIOT
ELRTTY      | AHMORS
AOOTTW      | EGKLUY
ABBJOO      | ABILTY
EHRTVW      | ACDEMP
CIMOTV      | EGINTV
DISTTY      | GILRUW
EIOSST      | ELPSTU
DELRVY      | DENOSW
ACHOPS      | ACELRS
HIMNQU      | ABJMOQ
EEINSU      | EEFHIY
EEGHNW      | EHINPS
AFFKPS      | DKNOTU
HLNNRZ      | ADENVZ
DEILRX      | BIFORX
```

I am trying to construct an algorithm that can be used on any western language to construct similar dice sets.

Comment: I am not sure, whether better chance of getting an answer is here or at [boardgames.SE](http://boardgames.stackexchange.com/). Note: That site is still in beta.